# Using Createjs and Chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, chart.js, createjs

I'm currently trying to use chartjs to make the chart and use createjs position it into the stage. Any ideas on how to puts a chartjs chart(radar) into createjs canvas stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like chart.js is canvas-based. You can use a canvas a a source for an EaselJS bitmap, and include it in your content.

```
var chart = document.getElementById("chart-canvas-id");
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(chart);
stage.addChild(bmp);
stage.update();
```

The EaselJS Stage requires children to be a display object, so this is probably the best way to work with chart.js content.

Comment: Thank you this was the solution I needed!